# Hanging when trying to play OpenCv frame

Tags: c++, opencv

I Am trying to write an application which transmits video and then playing it. But for start I Am trying to just open video and play it and I am having troubles with that.
Here is my code:

```
VideoPlayer::Play()
{
CvCapture *capture = cvCreateFileCapture(m_FileName.c_str());
    IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

    int frame_number = 0;

     cvNamedWindow("stream_server", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);


    while (true)
    {
        if (!frame)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed\n";
            break;
        }

        cvShowImage("stream_server", frame);


        ++frame_number;
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
}
```

Thing is - when I run this program, I see videoWindows appears but it shows grey screen and hangs with sand clock.

Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `waitKey` in order for the window to be updated. This will stop if the user presses the letter 'c':

```
int c = waitKey(10);
if( (char)c == 'c' ) { break; }
```